# I want to know that whether the Salesforce data can be integrated using Workamajig

Tags: integration

Can we do integration of Salesforce data on Workamajig ? Please provide any link for research on this topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can create a web tab within Salesforce called "Workamajig" and link it to the Workamajig website. Then when a user is in Salesforce they can click the Workamajig tab and the website is displayed. This is a UI integration. For a business logic or data integration that would be different but you didn't specify the type of integration needed.

Comment: Thanks @Francis, I'll let you know about my requirements once I go through all stuff you've taught.

Comment: Hi @Francis, My Requirement is to Integrate my Salesforce Accounts' to the Accounts in Workamajig.

Comment: Based on looking on the Internet it doesn't look like Workamajig have an API, so integrating with it doesn't seem likely for account integration. You maybe able to do a daily export of data that you can upload into Salesforce but may have to be manual or partially automated. But I have not used Workamajig before so no expert in it.